# How to create a table with multiple calculations?

Tags: sql

If I do one calculation with one join:

```
SELECT
    SUM(friends_made) as calc1, table2.group_id
FROM
    friends_made_table as table1
INNER JOIN
    grouped_users as table2 ON table1.user_id = table2.user_id
GROUP BY 
    table2.group_id
```

The result I get is:

```
calc1 | group_id
-----------------
400   |   1
320   |   2
330   |   3
```

But I also need another calculation (calc2) with the same inner join on table1 but with a different table (table3)

```
SELECT
    SUM(request_accept) AS calc2, table1.group_id
FROM
    friends_accept_table AS table3
INNER JOIN
    grouped_users as table1 ON table1.user_id = table3.user_id
GROUP BY
    table1.group_id
```

Result is:

```
calc2 | group_id
-----------------
100   |   1
150   |   2
120   |   3
```

How can I join these two queries and create a new table showing both of the calculations (calc1, calc2)?

```
calc1 |calc2 | group_id
-----------------------
400   | 100  | 1
320   | 150. | 2
330   | 120. | 3
```

EDITED to show tables/results and take out rounding

Comment: Please update your question to provide the DDL for the tables involved, sample data for those tables and the result you want to achieve based on your sample data

Comment: Can you tag the DBMS please ..?

Comment: Is rounding even necessary? It doesn't sound like friends and requests will involve fractions.

Comment: @NickW edited to show sample data and final result table I would like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A join will suffice as long as there is a common set of `group_id`s across the two results. You may otherwise need a left/right join or full join.

```
with data1 as (
    SELECT SUM(friends_made) as calc1, table2.group_id
    FROM friends_made_table as table1 INNER JOIN grouped_users as table2
        ON table1.user_id = table2.user_id
    GROUP BY table2.group_id
), data2 as (
    SELECT SUM(request_accept) as calc2, table1.group_id
    FROM friends_accept_table as table3 INNER JOIN grouped_users as table1
        ON table1.user_id = table3.user_id
    GROUP BY table1.group_id
)
select calc1, calc2, d1.group_id
from data1 d1 inner join data2 d2 on d2.group_id = d1.group_id;
```

This does assume that your platform supports CTE syntax. If it doesn't there are probably similar rewrites.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I needed and the results from the final join table match the calculations from the individual queries :D

Comment: just wondering can I also include another calculation from a different table (calc3,table3) into this query? or will this only work for two calculations?
EDIT: just tried and added a new inner join for d3, its working fine :)